# What ways are there to make sure router multicast tables are up to date?

Tags: router, multicast

I've been reading on IGMP v3 and think I understand the basics of how to join a multicast group - sending a [Membership Report Message](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3376#section-4.2).

But I'm not sure what the "best" or even conventional (usual) way to make sure group membership persists. Example being in case of router reboot. I don't think this is handled by prior APIs I've been using. At least not explicitly.

Ways that come to mind, in no particular order:

- Resend join message in case address turn silent.
- Query Membership, resend join on mismatch.
- Wait for... something sent from rebooted router? Or something suggesting the table has been dropped? Not sure what that'd be exactly.

When I say "good way" I mean a way that is robust, and either or both makes for low traffic and fast recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A router configured to forward multicast to clients/receivers in attached subnets (by listening for and acting upon their IGMP messages) is usually also the designated *IGMP Querier* for the given attached subnet.

After a reboot, it will send out some IGMP general queries ("everyone, please report!") into the attached subnet, and the interested clients will respond with IGMP messages (group reports or joins) for the groups thery're interested in receiving.  Remember: IGMP is a thing between mcast receivers and the mcast routers in the given subnet (... and for the switches to snoop on).

Pretty much at the same time, the router will have established a PIM neighborship with its upstream PIM neighbors, and (depending on the operating mode) will have established a way to know beyond which of its upstream interfaces to find the Multicast RendezVous point. PIM is spoken between multicast enabled routers, and it's based on the unicast routing protocol spoken between them. The receiver's IGMP messages (join, leave) are translated into to PIM messages (Join/Prune) and forwarded upstream int the multicast network (in extenso: towards the RendezVous Point). This way, the upstream multicast routers are instructed on which of their downstream interfaces they need to forward which multicast streams.

Later on during operation, the IGMP Querier will multicast the same kind of general IGMP query into the attached receiver subnet(s) at regular intervals, so receivers will (re)confirm their interest every so often.

Comment: I see, I should listen for Membership Query and then respond appropriately with a Membership Report. I very much appreciate the additional context!

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind, there are three (3) versions of IGMP. While v2 introduced an explicit leave type, there's no "join". To be part of any group a host includes that group in a membership report. State is maintained through periodic group membership queries. There will only be one *querier* per subnet - either a multicast router, or node running a querier service. (for resilience, more than one should be configured, but only one will ever be active. the querier doesn't necessary care about the answer, as the point is get reports to flood the network. an mrouter cares because it's sharing that information.)

In v1, leaving a group is done by letting it expire - not including it in your membership reports, eventually it will expire.

[See also: RFC1112, RFC2236, RFC3376]